# How can I get last inserted values for a user?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MYSQL table...

```
+----+---------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
| id | user    | val1      | val2          | val3       | last_modified_date  |
+----+---------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 |    0001 |         1 |             1 |          1 | 2014-03-31 16:53:29 |
|  2 |    0100 |         1 |             1 |          1 | 2014-04-01 10:32:50 |
|  3 |    0200 |         1 |             0 |          0 | 2014-04-01 10:34:13 |
|  4 |    0200 |         1 |             1 |          1 | 2014-04-01 14:43:47 |
+----+---------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
```

What I'm trying to achieve is getting all the last (in order of time) set of values created for the users.

In the example given we insert 0 for user 0200 but after 4 hours we insert 1. I want to be able to get the last value inserted (1).

I have this query:

```
select * 
from table 
where val3 = 1 
group by user 
order by last_modified_date desc;
```

And a more generic one

```
select * from table group by user order by last_modified_date desc;
```

These queries seems to be working fine for the example table. Are they correct for every case? How can I tell "select all the users that have val3 = 1 as their last inserted value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these two methods:

Option 1 - get the last record for each user and filter for `t.val3`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(last_modified_date) as last_modified, user
    FROM table
    GROUP BY user
) as tt ON t.user = tt.user AND t.last_modified_date = tt.last_modified_date
GROUP BY user
HAVING val3 = 1
```

Option 2 - get all the records for `t.val3 = 1` and remove those which are not last:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table tt ON tt.user = t.user AND tt.last_modified_date > t.last_modified_date
WHERE t.val3 = 1
AND tt.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * from table as t1
where val3 = 1 
and last_modified_date =
(select max(last_modified_date) as  last_modified_date from table as t2
where t1.user=t2.user and t2.val3 = 1 );
```

Comment: What if 2 users have the same `last_modified_date`, but its not the last record for one of them?

Comment: I also used val3=1 condition

Comment: My mistake, I missed `t1.user=t2.user`.